# Does Prototype.js support custom pseudo-classes?

Tags: jquery, mootools, css-selectors, prototypejs, pseudo-class

That is, can I define a selector called `:shiny` and do this?

```
$$('div.shiny') //undesired -- class based
$$('div:shiny') //desired -- logic based
```

This is available in MooTools and jQuery.

Comment: if you need it so bad, simply override Selector class (or at least extend it) so to make it support this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible now, you will need to wait for Prototype 1.7 which will be using [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) as the default selector engine

Comment: I'll look forward to that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

according to [$$](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) it supports:

```
$$('div:empty');
// -> all DIVs without content (i.e., whitespace-only)
```

Comment: What about where you were the one to define what ":empty" was?